# Как получить конкретное значение цены при совершении события

Tags: tradingview

Как получить значение цены при совершении события. Есть два события:

1. Пересечение macd_line и signal_line
2. Минимальное значение цены за последние 13 дней

Позиция лонг закрывается, когда наступает одно из событий

```
macdl = crossover(macd_line, signal_line)
lowestLow = lowest(low, 13)

stoplong = max (macdl, lowestLow)

if  (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit ("Sl_Buy", "Buy", stop=stoplong)
```

Но выходит ошибка: Cannot call 'min' with 'arg_2'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: series[float]

Т.е. сравниваю разные типы. Поэтому вопрос: как получитьконкретниое значение цены при совершении события crossover(macd_line, signal_line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача решена вводом переменной:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")

var macd_price = 0.0
[macdLine, signalLine, histLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macd_price := ta.crossover(macdLine, signalLine) ? close: macd_price
```